# Touching an object in a tweened animation?

Tags: android, animation

I'm having trouble porting a simple game I developed for the iPhone 
over to Android. The game has an animated ball which moves from Point 
A to Point B. The user must touch the ball before it reaches point B 
or lose the game. This was easy to implement on the iPhone using Core 
Animation since I could locate the current position of the ball by 
accessing its animation layer. In Android, I attempted to recreate the 
game using tweened animation and represented the ball as a Drawable. 
My issue is that I can't determine if the user is touching the spot 
because the Drawable apparently bounds do not update as the ball 
visually moves - making the program think the ball is always in its 
original position. While searching these forums I saw an Android team 
dev. confirm that you can't get the current location in a tweened 
animation but offered no solution for a workaround. Can I accomplish 
this on the Android using my current approach? If not, what approach 
should I use? 
Best regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

> Can I accomplish this on the Android
>   using my current approach?

I doubt it. Android's tweened animations are not really designed for games.

> If not, what approach should I use?

Implement the game using 2D drawing on the `Canvas` -- see the `LunarLander` sample in your SDK.